# Can i use series expansion when i don't have any idea to solve ML inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration

As already mentioned on my title i need to estimate a contour integration on a straight line and have to show the value is $0$ when $R$ goes to $\infty$. Here is my contour:
[image: Bromwich Contour]

I'm working on $\Psi^2$. The function itself is
$$e^{zt}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right),\quad t>0$$. And for your information, the straight vertical line goes from $\sigma-i\infty$ to $\sigma+i\infty$.

My parametrization:
$$\Psi_2: z=-\xi+iR,\quad \xi\in[-\sigma,0]$$

The reason i wrote $-\xi$ is i don't want to write $\xi\in[\sigma,0]$ which the notation of the interval is wrong since $\sigma>0$

So,
$$I_{\Psi_2}:=\int_{\Psi_2} e^{zt}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)\Bbb dz = -\int_{-\sigma}^0 e^{(-\xi+iR)t}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{-\xi+iR+1}{-\xi+iR}\right)\Bbb d\xi. $$

Then, for estimating the integral i need to put a modulus on it:
$$\begin{align}
\left|I_{\Psi_2}\right| &\leq \left| -\int_{-\sigma}^0 e^{(-\xi+iR)t}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{-\xi+iR+1}{-\xi+iR}\right)\Bbb d\xi\right|\\
&\leq \int_{-\sigma}^0 \left|e^{(-\xi+iR)t}\right| \left|\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{-\xi+iR+1}{-\xi+iR}\right)\right|\Bbb d\xi
\end{align}$$

Because $\left|e^z\right|\leq e^{|z|}$ and $|(-\xi+iR)t| = t|-\xi+iR| \leq t(|-\xi|+|iR|)\leq t|R-|\xi||$. Since $R$ is a big number then the last expression is $t(R-\xi)$ and $|e^{iRt}|=1$.

Then using the Laurent series at $z=\infty$
$$\operatorname{Log}\left(1+\frac 1z\right) = \frac 1z - \frac{1}{2z^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac 1z\right)^3\right)\approx \frac 1z$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\sigma}^0 \left|e^{(-\xi+iR)t}\right| \left|\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{-\xi+iR+1}{-\xi+iR}\right)\right|\Bbb d\xi &\lessapprox \int_{-\sigma}^0 e^{\xi t} \frac{1}{R-\xi}\Bbb d\xi\\
&\leq \frac{1}{R} \int_{-\sigma}^0  e^{\xi t} \Bbb d\xi \tag{$\sup\{\xi\in[-\sigma,0]\}=0$}\\
&= \frac{1}{Rt}(1-e^{-\sigma t})
\end{align}$$

Which approaches to $0$ as $R\to\infty$. But is this valid? When i tried to check the graph (real plane), seems like $\frac 1x > \ln(1+1/x)$ for $x>0$.

My second doubt is using $\sup\{\xi\in[-\sigma,0]\}=0$ for the denominator to get rid of the variable and makes it easy to calculate since if i include the variable, i will come to something involving exponential integral $\operatorname{E}_1(x)$

Please, if you have better approach to solve this ML inequality and show the thr value of the integral is $0$ as $R\to \infty$, kindly tell me. Thanks in advance!